# react router redirects to home page on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, react-router

I have the following code:

```
let routes = 
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Authentication} />
            <Route path="/test" exact render = {props=> <Authentication/>} />
            <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
        if(this.props.isLoggedIn){
            routes = 
                <>
                    <div className='mobile-header' onClick={this.handleNavBarShow}>
                        <p className="mobile-menu-icon">
                            <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </p>
                    <p>Title</p>
                    </div>
                    <NavBar toShow = {this.state.showMobileNavBar} 
                            onClicked = {(e)=>this.handleShowAndHide(e,true)}
                    />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path ="/" exact render = {props=> <Authentication/>}/>   
                        <Route path ="/a" exact render = {props=> <Test1/>}/>
                        <Route path = "/b" exact render ={props =><Test2/>}/>
                        <Route path = "/c" exact render ={props =><Test3/>}/>

                        <Redirect to="/" />
                    </Switch>
                </>
        }
        return (
        <Router>
            <div className = "layout" onClick={(event)=>this.handleShowAndHide(event,false)}>
                {routes} 
                {showSideBar}         
            </div>
        </Router>
        )
```

problem is when this.props.isLoggedIn === true, whenever i try to reload a route "/a" "/b" "/c", or type it in the adress bar directly  it redirects to the "/" page. In the Test1 /Test2 /Test 3 components there are links to one another and it works fine.
also it works fine with reloading and direct typing when this.props.isLoggedIn !== true.
what could be the problem?

Comment: update:if I add:
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Authentication} />
            <Route path="/test" exact render = {props=> <Authentication/>} />
<Route path ="/a" exact render = {props=> <Test1/>}/>
            <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
then it works as expected for the "/a" route in both cases

Comment: Where & how is `isLoggedIn` passed as a prop to this component? Sounds like there is *some* asynchronous authentication check or global state population. Are you using redux or something similar?

Comment: thanks. Yes I do use redux and the isLoggedIn prop is passed to the component from redux.there is no asynchronous authentication check though, i just check a cookie.

Comment: Well, either way, I think you should use some "pendingCookieCheck" state that conditionally renders alternative UI until you confirm the `isLoggedIn` state where you can then start rendering your routes.

Comment: thanks!! that seems to work. care to explain why?

Comment: All the react "state" is in memory, so when you reload the page the `isLoggedIn` state is reset, likely back to a "false" value and on the initial render the `if(this.props.isLoggedIn)` path isn't taken, hence why you get bounced back to your unauthenticated routes and since the URL no longer matches a route you get redirected back to your home `"/"` route..

Comment: you are right,thanks again